# Ballot operation with Taquito and Beacon SDK

Tags: taquito, beacon, ballot

I'm trying to send a ballot operation with Taquito and Beacon SDK. Here's my code:

```
const currentProposal: string = (await Tezos.rpc.getCurrentProposal())?.toString() || "";
const branch: string = await Tezos.rpc.getBlockHash();
const period: number = (await Tezos.rpc.getCurrentPeriod()).voting_period.index;

const op = {
    "branch": branch,
    "contents": [
        {
            "kind": TezosOperationType.BALLOT,
            "source": userAddress,
            "period": period,
            "proposal": currentProposal,
            "ballot": ballotValue
        }
    ]
};

/*
Values I got:

        branch: 'BLrLfk6Z3vXx3EzNjkFz4dQEzNKZ1AZTUv5ecw4AADvPjWFHkTS',
        contents: [
            {
                kind: 'ballot',
                source: 'tz1...',
                period: 79,
                ballot: 'yay',
                proposal: 'PtKathmankSpLLDALzWw7CGD2j2MtyveTwboEYokqUCP4a1LxMg',
            },
*/

const hash = await wallet.sendOperations([
    op
]);
```

I'm getting the following error, it seems coming from beacon-sdk:

[PARAMETERS_INVALID_ERROR]:Some of the parameters you provided are invalid and the request could not be completed. Please check your inputs and try again.

The pkh I use as source is not a delegate, so I'm expecting an error. More likely something like "no keys for the source contract tz1..." as with `tezos-client submit ballot`, not a format error.

The target is to have to confirm the operation with connected Temple wallet.
When I try it with a simple transaction operation, it's ok, so my wallet is well initialized.

Is my operation not correctly formated ?
Are Taquito or Beacon SDK suitable with ballot operation ?
Or maybe Beacon SDK checks if phk is a delegate and returns this error if not ?

I want to be sure of that before taking time necessary to create a private network to test delegates and votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operation itself is formatted well, but you should pass to the wallet just the contents, like this:

```
const hash = await wallet.sendOperations(op.contents);
```

And yes, as you have already mentioned, when injecting it you will receive HTTP 500 with the error message:

```
[
  {
    "kind": "temporary",
    "id": "failure",
    "msg": "Error while applying operation {hash}:\nError:\n  The provided public key (with hash {address}) is not registered as valid delegate key.\n"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now.